# How and where should I fetch Image from image path

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I've very basic retrofit implementation:

```
public interface MoviesApi {
    @GET(Constants.POPULAR_MOVIES_URL)
    Call<AllMovies> getAllMovies(
            @Query("api_key") String apiKey
    );
}
```

**ViewModel**:

```
Call<AllMovies> call = RetrofitService.getAllMovies().getAllMovies(Constants.API_KEY);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<AllMovies>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AllMovies> call, Response<AllMovies> response) {
                staus.setValue(Status.SUCCESS);
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body());
                _allMovies.setValue(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AllMovies> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + t.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

And I'm using it inside my `recyclerView`:

```
  String currentUrl = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/518jo3Xlf8L._AC_.jpg";

        holder.title_text.setText(movieItem.getTitle());

        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(currentUrl)
                .apply(new RequestOptions().override(400, 600))
                .into(holder.imageView);
    }
```

Nothing speical here.

My response contain this field:

```
  "poster_path": "/e1mjopzAS2KNsvpbpahQ1a6SkSn.jpg"
```

that I should fetch from here:

```
https://image.tmdb.org/t/p
```

**My question is** - where should I fetch this image?

Should I create new `image` field in my movie model, and immediately after I call `getAllMovies` I should call `getPoster` for example and then insert the data to the `image` field I created?

Or just fetch directly from glide is enough?

It's worth to mention that I need to pass this image to other screen, when I click on recyclerView item for example

Should I create 2 retrofit instances for 2 base url(image and movies has different base url)?

Reference for tmdb image docs: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/images

Comment: This is a synchronization issue - You're trying to fetch the image for the recyclerview before it is displayed. By your own description, you aren't sure where to query the result of the image. One useful thing to keep in mind when approaching this is the activity lifecycle in Android https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/activity-lifecycle-in-android-with-demo-app/.  Anyways, the issue of downloading an image into a view in android is already solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android

Comment: Why not make the `poster_path` part of the movies response, so that you query all data once in one call to `getAllMovies()`?